# Opening form based on two criteria results in Type Mismatch error

Tags: ms-access

I have the following code to open a form to a specific record based on two criteria, the `Service User ID` field is of type `Integer` and `Purchase Order Number` is `Text`, when the code runs I get a `Type Mismatch` error

```
Public Function CmdOpenPurchaseOrder()
On Error GoTo Err_CmdOpenPurchaseOrder

    Dim stDocName As String
    Dim stLinkCriteria As String

    stDocName = "frmPurchaseOrders"

    stLinkCriteria = "[Service_User_ID]=" & Forms![frmPurchaseOrderList].[Service_User_ID] And "[Purchase_Order_Number]=" & "'Forms![frmPurchaseOrderList].[Purchase_Order_Number]'"

    DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, , , stLinkCriteria

Exit_CmdOpenPurchaseOrder:
    Exit Function

Err_CmdOpenPurchaseOrder:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_CmdOpenPurchaseOrder

End Function
```

Individually the criteria works fine but together the error appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should read:

```
stLinkCriteria = "[Service_User_ID] = " & Forms![frmPurchaseOrderList].[Service_User_ID] & " And [Purchase_Order_Number] = '" & Forms![frmPurchaseOrderList].[Purchase_Order_Number] & "'"
```